# AD DS User Change its own password programmatically in c# framework 4.5 and later WinServer 2016 Win10

Tags: ldap, passwords

After days on searching and testing I give up.
Of course I try to follow similar case finded here and somewhere else but with no luck.
I'm writing a program that uses LDAP to authenticate users.
Stating server side is OK and well configured.
The problem is the follow:
During login process I'm able to detect if the "User Must Change password at next logon" flag is set, so i need to prompt the user to change the password.
Preamble I need to perform all communication with server encrypted so basically using port 636.

What I try up to now is:

```
ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, locDomain, null, options, locUsername, txtOldPassword.Text))
{
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, locUsername);
    if (user != null)
    {
        if (user.GetUnderlyingObject() is DirectoryEntry directoryEntry)
        {
            directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", new object[] { txtOldPassword.Text, txtNewPassword.Text });
            directoryEntry.CommitChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But I got always a COMException at 'FindByIdentity' stating pratically User name or password incorrect even if further investigation report the same error i use to understand that the flag "User must change the password at next logon" is set (8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C09058A, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v4563).
Then i tried other approach like:

```
ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.Negotiate | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer;
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, locDomain, domainFqdn, options))
{
   UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
   user.SamAccountName = locUsername;
   user.ChangePassword(locOldPassword, locNewPassword);
   user.Save();
   user.Dispose();
}
```

and i got again the same COMException stating user name or password is incorrect.

I tried also to use user.Name = locUsername; but i got same result as user are properly created with same Name and SamAccountName

what is expect is the user being able to change its own password even if it is expired or is set to be changed at logon but I'm really not able to get it works.

Does Anyone known how to perform this task?
Any help will be really apreciated.
Thank you

Comment: I did more test, if i remove the flag "User must change password at next logon" the code reported works as expected. Then i tried to force expiration of the password and then A different Exceptions went raised as expected, credentials are invalid.
I really don't know how to handle the matter, allow a user to change it's own password programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

> But I got always a COMException at 'FindByIdentity' stating pratically User name or password incorrect even if further investigation report the same error i use to understand that the flag "User must change the password at next logon"

This happens because `FindByIdentity` needs to use the user's credentials to connect to the domain controller via LDAP, and that also counts as a "logon". So if the password has been forcefully expired, logons through LDAP are not allowed because that would bypass the password change requirement.

If this is a webapp (i.e. hosted on a server), I believe it should use *its own* AD account to perform the initial user search as the first step; then it can look at the found account's UAC flags, prompt for password change if needed, then finally do a second LDAP bind using the user's provided password.

Comment: Happy new year, yes FindByIdentity I suppose i like a bind so it fails. No it is not a webapp actually so I can't login with a user with elevated rights and then set a new password pretending to be the user in order not to expose the AD to some sort of attack from an elevated user. Any further help will be highly apreciated.